# Make sendAction() execute first

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So I have something like this:

```
function() {  
    this.sendAction("myAction");
    this.doSomething();
}
```

How can I make the code within "myAction" execute first before this.doSomething()?

Comment: The short answer is you can't. If you used a closure action, and it returned a promise, you'd be able to wait for it to resolve before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `this.sendAction` run a callback to run `this.doSomething`.

Like this:

```
this.sendAction = function(action, callback) {
    console.log(action);
    callback();
}

this.sendAction('myAction', this.doSomething);
```

Or `Promise`s as locks suggested.

Comment: Probably wouldn't want to override `this.sendAction` though. You'd invoke the callback in your actions hash on the parent component.